# SOLVED - CiviCRM Cron Configuration on Drupal 7 throws unable to find key error with duplicate root folder in error message

Tags: configuration, cron, error-page

I tried to find the answer here, in the old forum, and many searches on the Googoracle to avail. Here is my problem

The requested page "/cm_starterkit_moderate-7.x-2.0-beta7/cm_starterkit_moderate-7.x-2.0-beta7/civicrm-cron/passthrough?key=*******(masked)" could not be found.

Obviously, it's not duplicated.  And I wanted to change the directory structure, but ran into problems with that. :/

Any ideas on how to fix this? This seems to only be a problem with the CiviCRM Cron config screen.

I am on Drupal 7.4.3 and CiviCRM 4.7.6.

Thanks Chris!

Answer (score 1):

welcome to the Stack,

You need to update your directories!

Head on to "Administer" then "System Settings" and then directories. Point the locations to the right place and save. Don't forget to "clear cache and update paths" afterwards!

Comment: Also check the filesystem paths in `civicrm.settings.php` :)

Comment: Kicking myself for not saying that - nice one Chris.